# TaskDialog in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use the TaskDialog but encountering some problems:

1. I am getting the following error:

> Error 1   Could not find file
>   'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls,
>   Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=*,
>   PublicKeyToken=6595b64144ccf1df,
>   ProcessorArchitecture=X86,
>   Type=win32'.  WpfApplicationUnleashed

I have changed my manifest file to as per this link 
http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/06/16/The-Application-Manifest-Needed-for-XP-and-Vista-Style-File.aspx

2) If I use this TaskDialog, I will see if the OS running is windows vista or higher and selectively use/ dont use TaskDIalog, however, is there any difference in TaskDIalog in Vista and Windows 7.I mean will have to filter windows vista and windows 7 also ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you running your app under the debugger? If so, try running it without the debugger i.e. press Ctrl+F5, or run it from Explorer. If it works without the debugger, then the problem is because of the Visual Studio hosting process, which is a special process which the debugger uses to host your real application when debugging to speed various things up.

To work around this, create a second copy of your manifest file called `YourApp.vshost.exe.manifest` in your project, and set it 'Copy to Output' to 'Copy if newer'.